# Firebase Emulators UI - cloud functions and auth with Vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

Has anyone actually hooked up the auth emulator in a vuejs or nuxtjs app?

I have read all the documentation on firebase and I have hooked up the firebase emulators to a test app.

However this example does not involve authentication emulators.

Can anyone help?